# DateTime conversion problem in SQL Server 2005

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005

Here I am using C# and SQL Server 2005. And my problem is, I have table in SQL Server like this

```
Status  ID     CreationDate            AccNo     Amount
 1      1001    5/27/2011 7:56:16 PM   100001    686700
 1      1002    5/27/2011 7:56:16 PM   10009      40000
```

when I am retrieving data like `select * from tablename`, then the date column will be displayed like below

```
Status  ID      CreationDate                AccNo    Amount
 1      1001     2011-05-27 19:56:16.110    100001    686700
 1      1002     2011-05-27 20:04:20.470    10009      40000
```

why it is changing like that and, how to change the date format `2011-05-27 19:56:16.110` to `5/27/2011 7:56:16 PM` ?

Thanks,
Anuradha J

Answer (score 3):

A datetime column just stores a date and time value. It doesn't apply, nor store, any formatting information.

If you need these datetimes in a particular format for presentation, then you either need to specify that format during `SELECT` (by using [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx) with an appropriate format specifier), or better, leave it up to whatever is consuming the results to perform conversion and formatting.

Looking at the format specifiers available for `CONVERT`, I can't actually see one that allows `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss`, so you'd need to perform two conversions, separately, for the date and time components, or as I say, leave it up to your C# code to perform the formatting. Ugly SQL way:

```
SELECT
    Status,
    ID,
    CONVERT(varchar(16),CreationDate,101) + ' ' +
       CONVERT(varchar(16),CreationDate,8) as CreationDate,
    AccNo,
    Amount
FROM
    tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

answer dont change it the databse, change how you use the data from the database. in your code.

store the retrieved result in a date time object, then you can do anything you want with it.
the data is the same.

or write a stored proc that changes the output to what ever you want.

look up time handeling in TSQL.

Answer (score 0):

In the code behind you can do the following. Bring the date without converting it into string.

```
DateTime dt;
string Temp1 = "Your Date from database";
if (DateTime.TryParse(Temp1, out dt))
{
     // If it is a valid date
     string date = dt.ToShortDateString();
     string time = dt.ToShortTimeString();
}
```